# ERROR : 401 loginpost URL timed out,

Tags: yodlee

While linking one of our bank account from HDFC bank india we see an error message stating :

ERROR : 401 : HDFC Bank (India) - Bank and Credit Card

As part of our internal proactive monitoring initiative, we have observed that agent is failing with 401 because loginpost URL timed out.

Let me know does these banks are not supported within yodlee or is there any access restriction.

Besides this API accepts invalid login too and returns has site(bank name) added successfully.

Let me know how to solve these problems

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when Yodlee is not able to connect with the Bank website in a defined time frame. This could happen due to various reasons,one of basic reason is that Site is taking too much time to load or open login page.

For your reference [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes) is the details about different error codes.

On your second question: Where you have mentioned that this API takes invalid login credentials as well.
To explain you the process- You'll provide the credentials(whether correct or incorrect) to this API, then Yodlee uses those credentials and try to login at the bank website while if site says that the credentials are invalid Yodlee returns the respective error code and message. Hope this helps.